# Distribución normal - Densidad de probabilidad

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

Quiero aplicar el concepto de distribución normal.

En concreto conocer la función de densidad de probabilidad.

Mi problema es que yo tengo una serie de datos guardados en una lista llamada `data` y se que para poder aplicar `.norm.pdf(data)` previamente tengo que haber calculado la media y su desviación estandard.

He estado leyendo la  [documentación](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html) y no soy capaz de sacarlas.

Se que existe `.mean()` y `.std()` pero imagino (y entiendo por la documentación) que la propia función `scipy.stats.norm` lo debe calcular.

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

**EDITO**
Pasos que sigo:

1)Tengo unos datos generados con `norm.rvs`

2) Hago `datos.mean()` y `datos.std()`

3) Hago `dist = norm(datos, loc=media, scale=desv)`

4) dist.pdf()

5) Muestro todo esto en un plot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que tienes un pequeño lío.

La función `scipy.stats.norm()` no es para calcular los parámetros de una distribución normal (pues para eso basta `.mean()` y `.std()`, como tú indicas), sino para obtener la ecuación continua de una distribución normal, dados sus parámetros.

La idea es que tú partes de la hipótesis de que el fenómeno que observas sigue una distribución normal (esa hipótesis puede ser correcta o no), pero esa distribución es una "abstracción", por así decir, una curva matemática a la que tus datos se ajustarían si tuvieras infinitos datos.

En la realidad, cuando tomas un conjunto finito de medidas, lo que tienes es una *muestra*. Esa muestra tiene un *histograma* (el número de veces que se repite cada observación) y ese histograma se parecerá a la función de densidad de una normal si en efecto el fenómeno observado tenía esa distribución como modelo subyacente, y si la muestra tiene muchos datos (cuantos más tenga, más se parecerá). En el límite, con infinitos datos, serán iguales. El histograma es una "realización" discreta de la abstracción matemática subyacente, que es continua, y que es la normal.

Dicho esto, puedes usar python con tus datos para:

- Verificar tu hipótesis de que tus datos provienen de un fenómeno que puede modelarse según una normal. Para ello usas [`scipy.stats.normaltest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.normaltest.html)
- Pintar el histograma de tus datos para ver si se parece o no a la normal, usando por ejemplo `matplotlib.pyplot.hist()`
- Si efectivamente es una normal, calcular sus parámetros, con `numpy.mean()` y `numpy.std()`.
- Obtener la ecuación continua de la curva que representaría a la "verdadera" distribución normal subyacente. Para esto era [`scipy.stats.norm()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html), y a la que le has de pasar la media y desviación antes calculadas.
- Pintar si quieres esta distribución continua encima de tu histograma, para ver cuánto se parecen, con `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`, usando como función para generar la curva a pintar `scipy.stats.norm().pdf()`.

También puedes usar la distribución que has obtenido con `scpy.stats.norm()` para generar números aleatorios que se ajusten a esa distribución, aunque si no entendí mal esto no es necesario para tus objetivos.

### Demo.

Supongamos que tenemos 1000 datos que siguen una distribución normal de media 10 y de desviación estándar 2. Estos datos saldrían de haberlos medido en algún proceso, pero para simplificar voy a generarlos con python. Podría usar `scypi.stat.norm` para generarlos, pero no quiero liar, ya que voy a reservar `scypi.stat.norm` para otra cosa. Así que usaré el `numpy` para ello:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.normal(loc=10, scale=2, size=1000)
print(np.mean(data), np.std(data))
```

Al ejecutarlo me sale que la *muestra* tiene media 10.0034052115156 y desviación 1.9774356539615665. Pero si lo ejecuto otra vez podrá salir otra cosa. Si la muestra tuviera infinitos elementos, la media sería 10 y la desviación 2.

Puedo pintar el histograma de esta muestra:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(data)
```

[image: histograma]

Ahora puedo usar `scipy.stat.norm` para crear una distribución normal continua con los parámetros que extraje de la muestra (observa que no son los "verdaderos" parámetros, pues esos nos son desconocidos en un caso real):

```
from scipy.stats import norm
dist = norm(loc=np.mean(data), scale=np.std(data))
```

Y puedo pintar juntos el histograma de los datos y el pdf de `dist`. Para que sean comparables, el histograma debe estar normalizado (la suma de todas las barras debe dar 1 y no 1000 como en el caso anterior), lo cual se logra pasando el parámetro `normed=True` a la función `hist`.

Por otro lado, para pintar el pdf, ya que esa curva es infinita, debemos elegir un valor mínimo y uno máximo en el eje x. Podemos elegir por ejemplo representar entre el percentil 0.001 y el 0.999 (y tomar 100 puntos para hacer esa gráfica)

```
x = np.linspace(dist.ppf(0.001),
                dist.ppf(0.999), 100)
plt.hist(data, normed=True, label="Muestra")
plt.plot(x, dist.pdf(x), "r-", label="PDF teórico")
plt.legend()
```

[image: Resultado final]

Comment: Entonces entiendo que: (1) tener los datos, (2) hacer `.mean()` y `.std()` de esos datos, (3) hacer `.norm()` pasándole los datos. (4) a ese resultado hacerle `.pdf()`, (5) Dibujar el resultado

Comment: El problema mío entonces es que no se pasarle esos parámetros y en la doc no veo cuando se los pasa :(

Comment: @NEA Cuando creas la normal le puedes pasar los parámetros `loc`y `scale` que representan respectivamente la media y la desviación estándar. (sí, los nombres no son nada intuitivos). Por ejemplo `distrib = norm(loc=10, scale=2)`. Luego ya puedes obtener `dist.pdf()`, por ejemplo, o generar números aleatorios que sigan esa distribución con `dist.rvs()`, etc.

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo para que quede más claro. Con gráficas y todo :-)

Comment: Primero de todo muchiiisimas gracias, esto lo hice pero el problema es que como no lo entendia al 100% y me DA UN ERROR pensaba que lo hacía mal. La cosa es que el error que me da es que la propiedad density es desconocida.

Comment: Leo aquí que debe ser por un tema de versión...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368471/attributeerror-unknown-property-density

Comment: @NEA Ah, ok. Bueno, pues cambio `density` por `normed`  para que sea más compatible

Comment: con normed me da este otro error :( UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Será la tilde de "teórico". Quitala.

Comment: Sí, me he dado cuenta después pero con normed la línea de PDF queda a ras de suelo. No hace la curva

Comment: @NEA A mi me sale bien... lo que describes ocurre cuando el histograma no está normalizado, y por tanto la gráfica va en el eje Y desde 0 a 200 aproximadamente, mientas que el PDF siempre va entre 0 y 1 y por tanto ni se ve en comparación. Por eso hay que normalizar el histograma, y `normed=True` (como parámetro de `plt.hist()`) es precisamente para eso.

Comment: Lo arreglé! Muchísimas gracias por todo!!!